# Installing Microsoft Anti-Malware or Symmantec endpoint protection on Service Fabric VM's

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Anyone installed either Microsoft Malware Protection or Symmantec End Point Protection on the Service Fabric VM's. The Azure Security Center says it's possible, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

When you create the cluster, there is no extension option to add malware protection (that I could find). After you create the cluster, when you RDP into the servers, PowerShell Get-AzureRmVm can't find the ServiceName to use PowerShell to install the anti-malware. (I can get both those options to work on standalone VM's)

I'm thinking I'm missing something really simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Why? Ideally service fabric would be inside a data center, or at least not accessible from outside. Why degrade performance?

Comment: Three reasons why. 1) It's in Azure, hosting Web API microservices written with .NET that are externally exposed to mobile apps. 2) Anti-Virus on the servers is a regulatory requirement. 3) Probably my own sheltered lifestyle, but I don't recall seeing any data center hosted servers that aren't running end point protection as a last line of defense.

Comment: What ports are open? It's behind a load balancer on a private network and doesn't have any significant services running (famous last words)

Comment: 19000 for the dashboard. Each SF VM has an RDP port exposed through the load balancer (3389, 3390, etc.) Each application exposes a unique port through the load balancer for its Web API.

Comment: OK agreed. So can rdp be spoofed. Can 19000 be spoofed.  Basically what I'm saying is that I personally don't think you need malware checking but I'm happy to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is VM level config and so is usually managed via a custom VM image that already has things set up or via a VM extension. There's guidance around setting up antimalware in a cluster [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresecurity/2016/10/07/add-microsoft-antimalware-to-azure-service-fabric-clusters/).

```
# Script to add Microsoft Antimalware extension to VM Scale Set(VMSS) and Service Fabric Cluster(in turn it used VMSS)
# Login to your Azure Resource Manager Account and select the Subscription to use
Login-AzureRmAccount
# Specify your subscription ID
#$subscriptionId="SUBSCRIPTION ID HERE"
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
# Specify location, resource group, and VM Scaleset for the extension
#$location = "LOCATION HERE" # eg., “West US or Southeast Asia” or “Central US”
#$resourceGroupName = "RESOURCE GROUP NAME HERE"
#$vmScaleSetName = "YOUR VM SCALE SET NAME"
# Configuration.JSON configuration file can be customized as per MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771716.aspx
#$settingString = ‘{"AntimalwareEnabled": true}’;
# retrieve the most recent version number of the extension
$allVersions= (Get-AzureRmVMExtensionImage -Location $location -PublisherName “Microsoft.Azure.Security” -Type “IaaSAntimalware”).Version
$versionString = $allVersions[($allVersions.count)-1].Split(“.”)[0] + “.” + $allVersions[($allVersions.count)-1].Split(“.”)[1]
$VMSS = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -VMScaleSetName $vmScaleSetName
Add-AzureRmVmssExtension -VirtualMachineScaleSet $VMSS -Name “IaaSAntimalware” -Publisher “Microsoft.Azure.Security” -Type “IaaSAntimalware” -TypeHandlerVersion $versionString
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmScaleSetName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $VMSS
```

The Service Fabric team does have guidance on [how to configure your environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-standalone-deployment-preparation#environment-setup) that includes the information about the exclusions you'd want to add. Those include:

```
Antivirus Excluded directories
Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric
FabricDataRoot (from cluster configuration)
FabricLogRoot (from cluster configuration)

Antivirus Excluded processes
Fabric.exe
FabricHost.exe
FabricInstallerService.exe
FabricSetup.exe
FabricDeployer.exe
ImageBuilder.exe
FabricGateway.exe
FabricDCA.exe
FabricFAS.exe
FabricUOS.exe
FabricRM.exe
FileStoreService.exe
```